# React Native Ios Error: permission denied , mkdir

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

When I run my project on ios , build successful but metro return me this error and app not running on simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a `npm` permissions related issue.

Try reinstalling [npm with a node version manager](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node#using-a-version-manager-to-install-nodejs-and-npm).

Or visit [the official doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).